# Is this the layout of memory in C?

Tags: c, memory

I am making a diagram for an infographic and I was wondering if anyone would be able to proof read this diagram and make sure its all valid/I'm not missing anything. The diagram is intended to show the registers on a 64 bit intel system, and the memory is supposed to resemble the memory layout of C. [image]

Also, this is going to like a "programming reference wallpaper". Does anyone have any other ideas for what information should be included? The wallpaper is intended for people who use C, Java, some assembely, reverse enginnering, and more

Comment: In general: without a proper context, this is simply too broad.

Comment: Oo another note, which tool did you use to create this infographic?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I am making it with photoshop

Comment: @SouravGhosh to put it in context, this diagram should medel the memory in c

Comment: It's "Kernel" not "*Kernal*".

Comment: The C-Standard does not specify anything of this. So you need to refer to a specific C implementation to let your diagram become truth.

Comment: @alk hah how did I miss that ;)

Comment: The diagram is close to a windows process / thread memory layout. There is a "per thread" area, using segment FS or GS (I forget which) that may get mappped into the virtual memory address space when used.

Comment: @ALK I know that the C standard doesn't specify this, but from the textbooks I have read as well as the online diagrams (search c memory layout), they all give something that resembles this and I was just trying to compile to most basic, yet informative one

Comment: In 64 bits the addresses go beyond 0xffffffff

Comment: @Dani, is it just 0xffffffffffffffff ???

Comment: @yasgur99: You have two regions, 0 - 7fffffffffff and ffff800000000000 - ffffffffffffffff

Comment: This is at least one or two abstraction layers below what C is all about. You don't show a depiction of amino acids & lipids and call it a picture of your dog. Yes, your dog _contains_ those things at some level, but it's not really what "being a dog" is all about.

Comment: What's a "kernal"?

Comment: The diagram has absolutely nothing to do with C whatsoever in any shape or form. C doesn't specify any particular memory layout and doesn't mention most of the words used in the diagram. A change from 0xffffffff to 0xffffffffffffffff will do this diagram very little good.